# this.fb.group({ is not a function in angular?

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, angular2-forms, mean, angular-unit-test

I have the following code,

```
** component.ts,

 constructor(public cdr:ChangeDetectorRef, public fb:FormBuilder) { 
   this.buildForm();
 }



buildForm(): void {
 this.feedbackForm = this.fb.group({
  suggestedAScore: ['', [Validators.pattern(/^[0-9]+$/),Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(5), Validators.minLength(5)]],
  minScore: ['', [Validators.pattern(/^[0-9]+$/),Validators.required,Validators.minLength(1),Validators.maxLength(1)]],
  maxScore: ['', [Validators.pattern(/^[0-9]+$/),Validators.required,Validators.minLength(1),Validators.maxLength(1)]]
});
 this.feedbackForm.setValidators(this.minMaxValidator());
this.isFeedbackFormValid();
};
```

** spec.ts, (shallow render)

```
 describe('FeedbackOptionsComponent', () => {
  let shallow: Shallow<FeedbackOptionsComponent>;

 beforeEach(() => {
   shallow = new Shallow(FeedbackOptionsComponent, AnnualCompensationModule)
   .provide(FormBuilder)
 });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(FeedbackOptionsComponent).toBeTruthy();
 });
```

When I run the code I am getting the test case,I am getting the following error:

```
this.fb.group({ is not a function
```

I am new to unit test cases.Can anyone please suggest me help to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `neverMock` to init `FormGroup` module

```js
import { FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';

 describe('FeedbackOptionsComponent', () => {

 Shallow.neverMock(FormsModule);

   beforeEach(() => {
   shallow = new Shallow(FeedbackOptionsComponent, AnnualCompensationModule);
 });

  });
```